# small version of minsdkversion ? how can i fix it ?

Tags: android, apk, signed

this is my code and it says that the error is i used a small version of minsdkversion ? how  can i fix it ?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ismailtaibi.ismagame.spidermanjamp"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
}
```

and this is the error

Error:C:\Users\ismaprod\StudioProjects\android3\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-73 Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4] C:\Users\ismaprod.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-11.0.4.aar\05bb078fa695de7980fb2889ef215c7e\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 11
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 11,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4] C:\Users\ismaprod.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-11.0.4.aar\05bb078fa695de7980fb2889ef215c7e\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 11
  >   Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 11,
  >       or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
  >       or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 7s

Comment: Check at defaultConfig minSdkVersion 11. Change it to at least 14. The library com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4 requires that. Hope it helps.

Comment: The minimum required sdk version for the latest Google Play Services is 14 and you have it set to 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dependencies, you have

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

This dependecy need the Android SDK 14 or higher. TO fix this, change your min Android SDK version to 14 :

```
minSdkVersion 14
```

Edit : set Compile SDK Version to the same value as Build tools version :

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

Comment: Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: it work thank you . b ut i had another problem which is $

Comment: Error:Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseNdk'.
> Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported

Comment: native build system.
  Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration. For more information, go to:
   https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html
  Alternatively, you can use the experimental plugin:
   https://developer.android.com/r/tools/experimental-plugin.html
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2m 36s